# JProgressBar update not working

Tags: java, swing

I have some code that moves files around and would like to implement a progress indicator while the files are being copied, but I'm having problems getting the progress bar to update - it just stays at 0.  Here is the relevant code in question:

```
            public class SomeClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener
            {
                private static SomeClass myprogram = new SomeClass();
                private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            myprogram.initGUI();
                        }
                    });
                }

                private void initGUI()
                {
                    JButton button1 = new JButton("Another Button");
                    JButton button2 = new JButton("Copy");
                    // other GUI Code
                }

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {       
                    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                    String text = button.getText();

                    if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Copy"))
                    {           
                        copyFiles();
                    }
                    else
                    {           
                        doSomethingElse();
                    }
                }

                public void copyFiles()
                {       
                    for (int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
                    {
                        //Code to copy files
                        progressBar.setValue((i * 100) / someNumber);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Do I need to use SwingWorker to get this working properly?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Short answer, yes (or at least copy the files some other thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question as to why your progress bar ain't updating:

Your *JProgressBar* ain't updating because you're blocking the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT) in your *copyFiles()* method.

You should never ever block the EDT with long-running operation.

What happens it that the *actionPerformed* callback is called from the EDT, so you're calling *copyFiles()* from the EDT too.

You should run the *copyFiles* from another thread.

> Do I need to use SwingWorker to get this working properly?

SwingWorker would, indeed, be one way to run the *copyFiles()* code from outside the EDT.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html). [Here's](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/making_progress_with_swing_s) a usage example.

Answer (score 0):

YOUR answer is:

```
progressBar.update(progressBar.getGraphics());
```

Comment: This wrong, but sufficient to handle small example.Dont sweat on small things